# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 on centos 6.5

Tags: python, django

When I try to install pyodbc on centos6.5 for python3.4 and django1.8 I have this error:

[image]

Someone can help me to fix this error.

Comment: Please include the error as text (not an image). Images are difficult to read and can't be searched.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to correct gcc problem:

You need to reinstall gcc , gcc-c++ and dependencies.

For python 2.7

`$ sudo yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel
$ sudo yum -y install python-devel libxslt-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel
$ pip install "your python packet"`

For python 3.4

`$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
$ pip install "your python packet"`

Comment: I already have these packages installed but i have the same error. I cannot find python3-dev for centos6.5.

Comment: try this: sudo yum install python-devel

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 3 use:

```
sudo yum install python3-devel
```

Adding version to the command solved this issue for me.